# How can I update text label with a function?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, label

How can I update label.text with a function?
This is my code:

```
func test() -> String!{
    return "2"
}

let label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(test)"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

But when I lunch the app,the screen shows me
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXfGT.png)

Comment: Try changing "\(test)" to "\(test())"

Comment: try this
label.text = test()

Comment: It gives me: Use of instance member 'test' on type 'MyClass'

Comment: solved by putting the function out of the class

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an instance method in the initializer for another property because you need to access `self` and that isn't available until the class has been fully initialized.

You can get around this by making your `label` a `lazy var` which won't be initialized until the first time it is accessed.  Then you can call `self.test()` to access your function:

```
lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = self.test()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

---

Alternatively, you could make `test` into a `static` function and then call it with `MyClass.test()`:

```
static func test() -> String {
    return "2"
}

let label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = MyClass.test()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```